# Get Column From Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the following (simplified) sql which selects user data from a main table `table1`. This query only select users who have not logged in since a given date. I use a sub query as the login table is separate from the main table. The two tables relate via a user ID column. This works perfectly.

```
// sql to get all records that haven't logged in since date above
$sql = "SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE '2016-08-01' > (SELECT MAX(t2.DateCol)
                 FROM table2 t2
                 WHERE t2.userId= t1.userId)";
```

My question is, is there a way of returning the value of `MAX(t2.DateCol)`?
I tired this but is didn't reconise the column

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.*, MAX(t2.DateCol) ....
```

FYI: This sql is parsed into a custom PDO function so no need to warn about insecurities of mysql functions.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: well you got to be warned about  insecirutues of PDO functions when they are used blatantly the same way as mysql functions

Comment: you seem to be new to mysql; what errors are you getting? check for them and tell us what it is. Consult http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and apply that to your code.

Comment: you must try reading mysql joins

Comment: seems you might have left the question. If so, you'll have to wait for someone else to see what those errors were, good luck

Comment: @YourCommonSense i actually bind the params and don't use them as a variable within the sql. I've simplified it so that the questions doens't get sidetracked from the sql and turns into a discussion about mysql insecurities (which happens on nearly all mysql questions). I've updated my question to simplify it further. thanks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the MySQL error is unknown column. I would expect this error with my sql because the sub-query is not within scope. As you say I am new to MySQL but even I can see that the sub query is not in scope. I would like a solution which brings this into scope without duplicating the sub-query again. I fear I may have to ask this question later when the USA guys are out of bed :(

Comment: that's because `WHERE` expects a column, not a string as per `WHERE '2016-08-01'` @steve

Comment: *"I fear I may have to ask this question later when the USA guys are out of bed"* - You're going to have to delete this question then if you plan on reposting. Otherwise it stands to get closed as an exact duplicate and you're going to get the same response in regards to the `WHERE` clause. You need to check against the column that is greater than the date you're trying to check for. @steve

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're wrong - you can pass a string for comparison? You are also new to MySQL? My current query, as in the example works flawlessly. With a string being used. That isn't the issue. Thanks for your time anyway. I'll delete the question for now as I don't seem to be getting anywhere. Thanks again.

Comment: @steve unknown column means just that; unexisting. And no, I am not new to mysql.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I get that the column doesn't exist thanks, I can clearly see the column isn't in scope. My question is how to get it in scope. I don't think anyone here knows the answer so i'll close this. Thanks all for your comments. If you follow my profile you may see this question get asked again and some bright spark will provide an answer i'm sure.

Comment: @steve ok steve, good luck :-) I hope it gets solved, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution (not knowing your skillset or data setup) - Move the sub-query in scope.

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.*,
(SELECT MAX(t2.DateCol)
                 FROM table2 t2
                 WHERE t2.userId= t1.userId) AS LastLogin
FROM table1 t1
HAVING '2016-08-01' > LastLogin ";
```

You will need to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` because you are comparing using an alias. If your query cannot use `HAVING` due to other factors then you'll need to repeat the subquery (not ideal).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the aggregation result, you should select from the aggregation. In order to do so group your aggregation by userid. You can use `HAVING` to only select desired ones.

```
select t1.*, t2.max_datecol
from table1 t1
join
(
  select userid, max(datecol) as max_datecol
  from table2
  group by userid
  having max(datecol) < date '2016-08-01'
) t2 on t2.userid = t1.userid;
```